# How to download CSV clicking a buttom without URL

Tags: r, csv, download

I would like to download the csv of this web --> https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/screener?exchange=NASDAQ

The problem is because i didn't see any URL.

How can i do to download this csv in R?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tip:

1. use Devtools with chrome or similar tool for other browsers.
2. Monitor network activity
3. Click the button and see what url shows up!

Then simply:

```r
library(jsonlite)
my.data <- fromJSON("http://that/long/url/you/will/find")
```

[image]